# SQL query for duplicate rows based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have 3 tables `movie`, `rating` and `reviewer`

`movie` has 4 columns `movieID`, `title`, `year`, `director`

`rating` has 4 columns `reviewerID`, `movieID`, `stars`, `ratingDate`

`reviewer` has 2 columns `reviewerID`, `name`

How do I query `reviewer` who rated the same movie more than 1 time and gave it higher rating on the second review.

This is my attempt at query to find rows with duplicate values in 2 columns (meaning the movie has been rated by 1 reviewer more than once), and then somehow I need to query `reviewer` who gave higher `stars` on second review.

```
SELECT reviewer.name, movie.title, rating.stars, rating.ratingDate
FROM rating
INNER JOIN reviewer ON reviewer.rID = rating.rID
INNER JOIN movie ON movie.mID = rating.mID
WHERE rating.rID IN (SELECT rating.rID FROM rating GROUP BY rating.rID, rating.mID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY reviewer.name, rating.ratingDate;
```

`movie` table

| movieID | Title | Year | Director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Gone with the Wind | 1939 | Victor Fleming |
| 102 | Star Wars | 1977 | George Lucas |
| 103 | The Sound of Music | 1965 | Robert Wise |
| 104 | E.T. | 1982 | Steven Spielberg |
| 105 | Titanic | 1997 | James Cameron |
| 106 | Snow White | 1937 | null |
| 107 | Avatar | 2009 | James Cameron |
| 108 | Raiders of the Lost Ark | 1981 | Steven Spielberg |

`rating` table

| reviewerID | movie ID | Stars | ratingDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201 | 101 | 2 | 2011-01-22 |
| 201 | 101 | 4 | 2011-01-27 |
| 202 | 106 | 4 | null |
| 203 | 103 | 2 | 2011-01-20 |
| 203 | 108 | 4 | 2011-01-12 |
| 203 | 108 | 2 | 2011-01-30 |
| 204 | 101 | 3 | 2011-01-09 |
| 205 | 103 | 3 | 2011-01-27 |
| 205 | 104 | 2 | 2011-01-22 |
| 205 | 108 | 4 | null |
| 206 | 107 | 3 | 2011-01-15 |
| 206 | 106 | 5 | 2011-01-19 |
| 207 | 107 | 5 | 2011-01-20 |
| 208 | 104 | 3 | 2011-01-02 |

`reviewer` table

| reviewerID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 201 | Sarah Martinez |
| 202 | Daniel Lewis |
| 203 | Brittany Harris |
| 204 | Mike Anderson |
| 205 | Chris Jackson |
| 206 | Elizabeth Thomas |
| 207 | James Cameron |
| 208 | Ashley White |

Expected result

| Reviewer | Title |
| --- | --- |
| Sarah Martinez | Gone with the Wind |

EDIT: I am using MySQL version 8.0.29

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? thanks

Comment: @ErgestBasha I am using version 8.0.29

Comment: @D-Shih Updated with data and result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
select re.Name,mo.Title
FROM (
      select reviewerID,movieID,ratingDate,Stars
      from rating r 
      where exists (select 1 
              from rating r1 
              where r1.reviewerID=r.reviewerID 
              and r.movieID=r1.movieID 
              and r.ratingDate>r1.ratingDate
              and r.Stars>r1.Stars
       )) as t1
inner join movie mo on t1.movieID=mo.movieID
inner join reviewer re on t1.reviewerID=re.reviewerID
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0c5d850ee3393b054d9af4c4ac241d96

The key part is the `EXISTS` statement

```
where exists (select 1 
              from rating r1 
              where r1.reviewerID=r.reviewerID 
              and r.movieID=r1.movieID 
              and r.ratingDate>r1.ratingDate
              and r.Stars>r1.Stars
```

which will return only the results on which you have the same user more than one movie, the rating Stars are bigger than the previos one based on the  ratingDate

Comment: The `existe` also work as well upvote

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you for explaning the ```EXISTS``` statement too, that is something new for me. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

we don't need to use `where in` with `rating` and `join` with `rating`

You can try to use `lead` window function to get the next start each `reviewerID` and `movieID` which represent duplicate rating (`order by ratingDate`)

then compare with your logic to find a newer start greater than older start.

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.Name,m.Title
FROM (
  SELECT reviewerID, 
         movieID,
         Stars,
         LEAD(Stars) OVER(PARTITION BY reviewerID, movieID ORDER BY ratingDate) n_start
  FROM rating 
) t1
INNER JOIN movie m ON t1.movieID = m.movieID
INNER JOIN reviewer r ON r.reviewerID = t1.reviewerID
WHERE Stars < t1.n_start
```

This sample data [sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3ea94e9ba397143aa6cca0b67fd0323) provide by @ErgestBasha

Comment: You need to include ratingDate condition to return only `reviewer who rated the same movie more than 1 time and gave it higher rating on the second review` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aca4ae2f6eba31fffb2d22c530e16f1a

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thank you for your remind I missing the condition fixed it